# docker still builds from cache even after system produce

Tags: docker

I run the following commands

```
docker system prune -a -f
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Then I do
`docker build .`

It still not picking up my code changes.

When I run the built container it still showing me old code.

Where is the docker stores the build cache?

Comment: can you try `docker build --no-cache .` and check if that works for you?

Comment: Have you recompiled or packaged your code? For example with `mvn package` for maven projects?